# How can I obtain URI components using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, uri, segment

How can I get URI components in AngularJS? For example I have http://domain.com/photo/1

So how can I get that second segment (=1) to a variable in angular? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Angular for that, you can simply do:

```
var url = document.URL.split('/'); // Get the current full url, eg: http://domain.com/photo/1 splitted by slashes
var lastArg = url[url.length];     // Get the last string after the last slash
```

Comment: I got this kinda working with changing url[url.lenght] to url[url.lenght-1] but.. This only works if url is like http://domain.com/photo/1 but if there is a trailing slash after 1 it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want a full url access you can use `$routProvider` and access URL params like so: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams